# My App is getting stuck on Splash Screen in iOS 13

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins, ios13

Ionic cordova App is working fine with iOS< 13 and all the androids. 
But after updating to iOS 13, It is getting stuck at splash screen.

Here is my list of plugins.

```
 cordova-background-geolocation-lt 2.9.1 "BackgroundGeolocation"
 cordova-custom-config 4.0.2 "cordova-custom-config"
 cordova-plugin-actionsheet 2.3.3 "ActionSheet"
 cordova-plugin-app-event 1.2.1 "Application Events"
 cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion"
 cordova-plugin-background-fetch 5.1.1 "CDVBackgroundFetch"
 cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.8 "Badge"
 cordova-plugin-camera 3.0.0 "Camera"
 cordova-plugin-cocoalumberjack 0.0.4 "CocoaLumberjack"
 cordova-plugin-device 1.1.7 "Device"
 cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.1 "Notification"
 cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
 cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.2 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
 cordova-plugin-local-notification 0.9.0-beta.2 "LocalNotification"
 cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.4 "Network Information"
 cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.1.0 "Splashscreen"
 cordova-plugin-sqlite-2 1.0.4 "SQLitePlugin"
 cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.3.0 "StatusBar"
 cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
 cordova.plugins.diagnostic 4.0.12 "Diagnostic"
 ionic-plugin-deeplinks 1.0.15 "Ionic Deeplink Plugin"
 ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
 phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 7.1.2 "BarcodeScanner"
 phonegap-plugin-mobile-accessibility 1.0.5-dev "Mobile Accessibility"
 uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator 5.0.4 "Launch Navigator"
```

Comment: Can you please check logs from safari device console

Comment: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Invalid Adapter: websql
PouchDB@ionic://localhost/build/vendor.js:86083:20
ionic://localhost/build/main.js:3043:65
Storage@ionic://localhost/build/main.js:3035:22
DocStorage@ionic://localhost/build/main.js:3186:32
LogStorage@ionic://localhost/build/main.js:7796:32
ionic://localhost/build/main.js:11992:106
ionic://localhost/build/main.js:10675:42
onInvoke@ionic://localhost/build/vendor.js:5105:39
ionic://localhost/build/polyfills.js:3:10149
ionic://localhost/build/polyfills.js:3:20245
onInvokeTas .....

Comment: Are you using any local db plugin for ionic?

Comment: Yes. I'm using PouchDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem with my code. I was using websql adopter in pouchdb.

```
      new PouchDB("name of the db", {adapter: 'websql'}):
```

Turns out, Apple discontinued the support for WebSQL in Progressive Web Apps. So instead of using websql, I'm using cordova-sqlite. This solves my problem.

```
      PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-adapter-cordova-sqlite'));

      new PouchDB("name of the db", {adapter: 'cordova-sqlite'}):
```